# How can i add a drop down extension to my existing menu

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I need to modify my existing menu and just add few more lines to make it drop down. 
Can someone please give me a code so i can add it to the Menu CSS?
I think I need to add something like > ul li li < but im not sure....

It's after the line 
/* Submenu---------

Please view my page source and tell me what modification i need to do

view-source:http://www.ellinikoarxeio.com/

(if you view it with google chrome, it's the lines 177 - 210 and then the line 723 for the page links...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pre-built solution for a [jQuery Drop Down Menu](http://javascript-array.com/scripts/jquery_simple_drop_down_menu/) that may be better for what you need.

I think using something like this is a bit easier than just "adding some dropdowns to a menu"

Comment: Thank you for your answer Robert. 
I really dont want to mess up the margin and padding atributes because i'm not good at this. I have never before uploaded javascripts and stuff like that. That why i was thinking that it might be easier to just add a few more lines to the existing menu.

Comment: In that case it might be easier for you to scrap your menu completely and just add the pre-made JavaScript to your project (You just include the file and reference it (find that here:http://www.ehow.com/how_2240576_add-javascript-html-documents.html)).  Once you have something working, you can work on customizing it a piece at a time until you are familiar enough with it to make any change you could ever need.  Then, you could use the same script on other projects and never have to worry about drop down menus again.